# Replace method does not work in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data bellow in my "Date" column.

Date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAzEM.png)

I just need to replace the dots for bar, but it doesn´t work...

I´m using the following code:

```
conn = pd.read_excel("database.xlsx",skiprows=3, usecols=['Date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(conn)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('.','/')
df.to_excel("removingdots.xlsx")
```

When the Excel file is exported, I have the same data, with the dots.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the bar? replace('.','\/')

Comment: `df['Date'].astype(str).str.replace('.','/', regex=False)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some assumptions of your df format but this should work;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'date': ['5.30.2021 10:22:00', '5.30.2022 11:45:08', '5.28.2022 10:45:13']})
# replace . with / in date column
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('.', '/',regex=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id                date
0   1  5/30/2021 10:22:00
1   2  5/30/2022 11:45:08
2   3  5/28/2022 10:45:13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the `Date` column to string type, then use `Series.str.replace` method to replace period with forward slash:

```py
df['Date'].astype(str).str.replace('.','/', regex=False)
```

Comment: This answer in in the "low quality answers queue".